# Laravel. Using WHERENOTIN

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

Basically I want to build tihs query in Laravel, but it does not work.

```
SELECT films.id, films.name AS film
FROM films
WHERE films.id NOT IN 
(   
    SELECT films.id
    FROM actors, actor_film, films
    WHERE actors.id = actor_film.actor_id
    AND actor_film.film_id = films.id
    GROUP BY films.id
 )
 ORDER BY films.id DESC
 LIMIT 600
;
```

Using a "whereNotIn" I have written these two queries:
The first one get all films in the Data Base that has at least an actor associated like this:

```
    $films_with_actors = DB::table('films')
        ->join('actor_film', 'actor_film.film_id', '=', 'films.id')
        ->join('actors', 'actors.id', '=', 'actor_film.actor_id')
        ->select( 'films.id')
        ->groupBy('films.id')
        ->get();
```

Now I want to get the films that do not have associated an actor. For that I am trying to get the ID that are not included in the previous method, like this:

```
    $films_with_no_actors = DB::table('films')
        ->whereNotIn('films.id', $films_with_actors)
        ->orderBy('films.id', 'desc')
        ->take(500)
        ->get();
        -
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I am giving you a basic solution based on the code you shared.

In laravel you have a method called [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) for retrieving an array with all the values for a given key.

Therefore, you can get only the ids for the $films_with_actors. Something like (based on your first query):

```
$films_with_actors = DB::table('films')
    ->join('actor_film', 'actor_film.film_id', '=', 'films.id')
    ->join('actors', 'actors.id', '=', 'actor_film.actor_id')
    ->select( 'films.id')
    ->groupBy('films.id')
    ->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Now you have an array with the ids and you can include that array in the whereNotIn clause of your second query:

```
    $films_with_no_actors = DB::table('films')
    ->whereNotIn('films.id', $films_with_actors)
    ->orderBy('films.id', 'desc')
    ->take(500)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. But does it means I have to run two querys? is not possible to embedd one inside the other, like in MySQL?

Comment: No worries, you can call it after you create the first query and it will work. Doing something like: $films_with_actors_ids = $films_with_actors->pluck('id')->toArray();